# How can I link to and open an accordion in another html page?

Tags: html, jquery, href, accordion

In my case, my home page only consists of a menu and closed accordions, each href in the menu when clicked on, opens a specific accordion & this works good.
My question is, if I have the same menu in other pages, not the home page, how can I let it hyperlinks to the home page & opens the specific accordion? They told me it can be done using Local Storage, but I don't know how to use it, any help please?

JQUERY CODE

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".expand").on("click", function () {
        $(".right-arrow").text("+");
        $(".detail:visible").slideUp();
        if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next().slideDown(200);
            $(this).find(".right-arrow").text("-");
        }
    });

    let click_state = localStorage.getItem("click_state");
    let ind = localStorage.getItem("ind");

    if (click_state == 1) {
        $(".expand").eq(ind).trigger("click");

        localStorage.removeItem("click_state");
        localStorage.removeItem("ind");
    } else {
    }

    $(".accord").each(function (index) {
        $(this).click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            localStorage.setItem("click_state", 1);
            localStorage.setItem("ind", index);
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="accord" href=""> Open 1st accordion </a> <br>
<a class="accord" href=""> Open 2nd accordion </a>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="accordion1">
        <div id="trickslist">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <div>
                            <h2 class="tipstricks">Exploring your Motivations to Quit Tobacco</h2>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">What to expect over time.</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Getting Ready: Strategies to conquer urges & set a quit date</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Quitting tobacco with medications</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Dealing with depression or stress</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Avoiding weight gain or alcohol</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expand" data-parent="#accordion1">
                        <div class="right-arrow">+</div>
                        <h2 class="tipstricks">Making your plan stick: relapse prevention</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div class="detail">
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think what you want is to use a hash in url. Then when page loads you read the hash `window.location.hash` to determine which panel to open. `https//mysite.com/pageName.html#panel1`. The `hash` is `"#panel1`

Comment: @charlietfl in the local storage function, is there another way to open an accordion from another page other than using local storage?

Comment: @charlietfl the hash loads the another page and get me to the panel I have but it doesn't open it, it's not a text or a section, it's an accordion that when clicked on it opens a section. I want to already hyperlink me from that page to the home page and opens the accordion for me.

Comment: Right... the link to home page would be like `<a href="/homepage.html#panel1">`. Then home page code needs to read the hash and open the correct panel. The benefit of doing it this way is the link can be shared as opposed to using storage for someone who hasn't been there yet

Comment: @charlietfl thank you but what should the home page code needs to be in order to read the hash & open the accordion?